openssh-client/openssh-server show different version than ssh -V
I wanted to upgrade my openssh versions to address CVE-2024-6387, and after running apt update and apt upgrade I see this output:
❯ sudo apt upgrade openssh-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
openssh-client is already the newest version (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.10).
openssh-client set to manually installed.
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# OpenSSH CVE-2024-6387 has been fixed for 22.04 LTS, 23.10 and 24.04 LTS.
# RegreSSHion: Possible RCE Due To A Race Condition In Signal Handling.
# For more details see: https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6859-1.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  python3-update-manager update-manager update-manager-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
❯ sudo apt upgrade openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
openssh-server is already the newest version (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.10).
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# OpenSSH CVE-2024-6387 has been fixed for 22.04 LTS, 23.10 and 24.04 LTS.
# RegreSSHion: Possible RCE Due To A Race Condition In Signal Handling.
# For more details see: https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6859-1.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  python3-update-manager update-manager update-manager-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
❯ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022

So both my openssh-client and openssh-server are on version 8.9p1-3 which is the patched version, but when I run ssh -V I see 8.9p1, which seems to be the unpatched version. Is this expected behavior of ssh -V or is it somehow pointing to the wrong version, and if so, how do I fix that?

Apt is correct, and the discrepancy is expected behavior. Recall that every stock install of Ubuntu will silently discover, download, and install install security-patched packages automatically (there are a couple exceptions, but OpenSSH is not one of them). Your output clearly shows that your system had already installed the patched package before you instructed it. Your confusion occurred because you tried to outwit the system.

But it says "8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10" right there in the ssh -V output, does it not?

The -3ubuntu0.10 for Jammy 22.04 is a package revision version string, not the OpenSSH itself version string (which is 8.9p1).  The base version of OpenSSH that's on the system excluding package revisions and patches included that way is 8.9p1.  By default, there, OpenSSH's -V (version) call will only state the base OpenSSH version and not the Ubuntu package revision data.
You are still patched, but because of the way the software compiles, you won't see the updated version string in OpenSSH's version output, which is expected behavior.
Note that you actually have to check the installed package revision, its patch sets, and the Security notices to identify what is or isn't included.  You're patched for CVE-2024-6387 (aka RegreSSHion) though, as long as the installed package version for the release is at or newer than the following (from the Ubuntu CVE tracker for CVE-2024-6487):

Ubuntu Jammy (22.04 LTS): 1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.10
Ubuntu Mantic (23.10): 1:9.3p1-1ubuntu3.6
Ubuntu Noble (24.04 LTS): 1:9.6p1-3ubuntu13.3

OpenSSH base versions earlier than 8.5p1 are unaffected.

I am not sure. The https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.8 says that 9.6p1 is affected.

@EugenKonkov The OpenSSH release docs do not account for security team distro-patching done by teams like the Ubuntu Security Team, Debian Security Team, etc.  The Ubuntu Security Team has taken the proper mitigations and patches and applied them to the versions of the OpenSSH binaries in Ubuntu.  They do this regularly because the OpenSSH packages are in main, which means they're supported actively by the Ubuntu Security Team, who are Canonical paid employees who do security related package maintenance.  Upstream notes don't have insight into downstream patching done independent of releases.

Do I understand correct, that if I have 9.6p1 or 8.9p1 versions then I am not vulnerable despite on  openssh.com/txt/release-9.8  states that vulnerable up to 9.7p1 (inclusively)? Sorry for dumb question.

@EugenKonkov reread my post which indicates the currently patched versions in supported Ubuntu releases.  The only way to know if you're actually unaffected is to check the corresponding CVE in the CVE tracker (which is linked!) and see which package versions have "Released" and green bars indicating the issue is patched in Ubuntu.  If you have 9.6p1 you're using 24.04, if you have 8.9p1 you're using 22.04, and you can check the installed version of your OpenSSH  with apt show openssh-server and see the installed versions of OpenSSH packages against known patched versions in the tracker
